# How to disable bash command horizontal scrolling to get new line instead

Tags: bash, inputrc

When I type a long command in a terminal from a SSH session, the content of the command line is scrolling to the left.

`$ echo this is a really long command line that goes on and on and on and on`

Might be displayed as:

`$ y long command line that goes on and on and on and on <`

I want the command line to go to a new line instead.
I tried to reset the behavior using `$HOME/.inputrc` but without success.

```
set horizontal-scroll-mode Off
```

Comment: did you make this change on your local computer or the machine you're ssh-ing into?

Comment: I did it on the remote machine. On my local machine (macOS), the bash command line adds a new line at the time the line comes to the end of the screen.

Comment: what is the value of `$TERM` on the remote machine?

Comment: `xterm-256color`

Comment: I found that the `bash` version that I'm using is installed by Homebrew. The issue appears only with this version (5.1.16(1)-release).